# using an object from different package

Tags: java

I have a problem, I have a package event which contains a class student in this class I have this method

```
public void addEvents( Event e) {
    if(e!=null)
        events.add(e);          
}
```

in a second package I have created an event and I want to call the above method to add the event created to a ArrayList

```
event.setDateEvent(new Date(day,month,year));
student.addEvents(event);
```

this error is displayed

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.ArrayList.add(Object)" because "this.events" is null
    at event.Student.addEvents(Student.java:48)
    at test.StudentTest.main(StudentTest.java:43)
```

Comment: Did you initialize `events` in the first class?

Comment: no I don't initialize event in the first class

Comment: I think that the problem because the two classes are not in the same package but I can't resolve this

Comment: The fact they are in different packages is irrelevant. You just need to initialize `events`, either in `Student`'s constructor or from a public method in `Student` you call from `StudentTest` or, if `events` is public, directly from `StudentTest`.